# Were all funds stolen from Mt. Gox finally returned to all users?

Tags: mtgox

Mt. Gox was hacked in June 2011, and some funds were stolen. There was a long winded account reclaim process.

At the end of this process, were all funds really returned to the satisfaction of all (legitimate) users? Is there a public statement / forum post that testifies to this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All the funds that were frozen have been returned. There are two types of funds that were not returned:

1. Some people claim funds of theirs were transferred out well before the freeze. They claim it must have been by the same person who got the account/password list, but before the big attack. They claim these funds have not been returned.
2. People who profited unfairly during the flash crash had their transactions undone. Some of them claim they are entitled to their profits. (Some people bought thousands of bitcoins at absurdly low rates.)

I think that people in the second category don't deserve to profit from the theft. As for the people in the first category, there are only two people that I know of who claim this and the amounts involved are quite small. So I think the true answer to your question is most probably "yes".

Comment: How were they able to undo the transactions for 2? I thought you couldn't undo bitcoin

Comment: @Casebash: These were not Bitcoin transaction, these were trades within Mtgox.

Comment: Exactly. These were either people who had Bitcoin balances in their Mt. Gox accounts, had currency payouts pending from Mt. Gox, or who had currency balances in their Mt. Gox accounts. For people who had taken their profits in Bitcoins and transferred them out of Mt. Gox, there's no way to undo them. (And, of course, that's what the bad guys did.)