# When MtGox was hacked on 15th June 2011, how many bitcoins were actually stolen?

Tags: security, mtgox, history, theft

When MtGox was hacked on 15th June 2011, how many bitcoins were stolen?

I remember at the time that news articles reporting the incident talked about the size of the sell order the hacker placed within the site, but failed to state the amount of bitcoins the thief managed to withdraw. Most of the stolen bitcoins were unable to be withdrawn, so MtGox was able to retrieve those by claiming them back from the controlled website account.

Please provide a link to support your answer.

Related question:
[Were all funds stolen from Mt. Gox finally returned to all users?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/163/were-all-funds-stolen-from-mt-gox-finally-returned-to-all-users)

Comment: Are you asking how many the hacker theif was able to sell within the exchange, or how many were successfully withdrawn before the site disabled withdrawals?

Comment: Two fairly complete summaries:

 - http://blog.zorinaq.com/?e=55
 - http://www.dailytech.com/Inside+the+MegaHack+of+Bitcoin+the+Full+Story/article21942.htm

Comment: @StephenGornick, I'm asking how many were withdrawn. I tried to word the question clearly, but would welcome edits to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MtGox, the hacker got [about 2000 BTC](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=83794.0#post_june_2011_mt_gox_incident).  A few real customers also appear to have purchased bitcoins at an artificially low price during the incident, withdrawn them, and kept them. This is estimated to amount to less than 650 BTC.

The details given at the above link are:

```
~June 2011 Mt. Gox Incident
Time: 2011-06-19T18:00 ± 1 h (theft), days ensuing (hacks & withdrawals)
Victim: Mt. Gox (some claim also customers)
Status: Thief uncaught
Amount:
Stolen by thief: 2000 BTC (official estimate)
Additional withdrawn from Mt. Gox: 643.27 BTC (lower bound)
Total: Lower bound 2643.27 BTC
Equivalent USD: 46970.91 $ (used last trade value; actual price at the time was not reliable)
Transactions: none released officially
The event's scale was widely disputed; some report a theft of almost 500000 BTC due to related account hacking. At this time, these reports seem to be unfounded and closer inspection puts the losses at closer to 2500 BTC. Some additional money was stolen by traders capitalizing on the dropping price and withdrawing in time, including toasty of the bitcointalk.org forums. Mt. Gox claims it has reimbursed customers for this theft.
```

Comment: Great post, thanks! I tried to find that information myself and didn't manage to.